# How to fix insecure SHA-1 and MD5 algorithm issues in com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.3?

Tags: java

I am using this dependency com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.13.3 version and getting SHA-1 and MD5 insecure algorithm errors during testing.

I tried with multiple versions of itext dependency but I am still getting these algo errors

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question, but it *looks like* you are using the deprecated / obsolete itextpdf 5 APIs.  For improved security, you should probably update your codebase to itext7.   See https://github.com/itext/itextpdf#readme

Comment: You may also be able to get itext 5 to use a more secure digest algorithm.  But that will depend on where and how you application is using the SHA-1 and MD5 algorithms in itext's checksum and message digests; i.e. what is triggering the warnings.  (Looking at the itext 5 codebase, it is clear that it does support more secure algorithms ...)  Also, understanding how your application code is triggering the warnings can help us / you to understand whether the warnings are significant ... or not.

Comment: Hi @StephenC I am just using itext version to merge images into pdf

Comment: So ... how is the strength / weakness  (security) of checksums even relevant to that?

Comment: Hi @StephenC   High Security risk I am getting after testing... Insecure hashing algorithm SHA-1 used......  com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader
Line 1031 in com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.java
com.itextpdf:itextpdf

Comment: So ... your application is **reading** a document that uses an SHA-1 checksum.  The "security problem" is apparently in the document that you are reading.  It has a weak checksum.  Is that really a problem?  How?  Why?  And is it problem in your application, or in whatever it was that is providing you with the document you are merging?

Comment: @StephenC I am creating a pdf by adding images only. There is no document I am using there

Comment: The code line says that you are READING the document!   That's what PdfReader does.   So maybe that is not the relevant line of code.  Look for the place in your code that generates the document that you are reading at that point ... and figure out why >that< is using a weak checksum.  (Common man .... use your code reading and problem solving skills!)

Comment: FWIW - based on what you have shown so far, this is not going to be solved by messing around with code versions.  The vulnerability appears to be in your application ... not in the version if `itext` you are using.